# Console dialog missing during debug in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, dialog, console, visual-studio-2017

I recently started working with Visual Studio 2017.  Jumping from 2010.

I created a new, very basic, console application and I am trying to test.  The code runs fine but I am not seeing a console dialog anywhere (I have breakpoints and also a Console.Read()).  I checked 'behind' all the windows.  See nothing in the task tray.

Any ideas?  Any new settings that I am not aware of?

Here is all of the code:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleTest2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Definitely a console application.

[Project Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zo3lt.png)

Comment: Are you sure that you have created a console application project?

Comment: Can you include your code?

Comment: I updated the original question